# exec() doesn't do anything

Tags: php, linux

When I type the following into the shell command prompt, it will convert a .docx file to a .pdf file.

```
HOME=/tmp libreoffice3.5 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_16_64.docx
```

But then when I run the following PHP script, nothing happens.  I have set /tmp/ayb permissions to 777, but still no go.  Any ideas?  Thanks

```
<?php
  $cmd='HOME=/tmp libreoffice3.5 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_16_64.docx';
  exec($cmd);
?>
```

EDIT-The following script produces the following results.  Note that the exec() take some time when the shell_exec() doesn't.

```
<?php
  $cmd='HOME=/tmp; /usr/bin/libreoffice3.5 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_16_64.docx';
  echo($cmd);
  exec($cmd,$out,$ret);
  echo('<br />exec()<br />$out='.print_r($out,1).'<br />$ret='.$ret);
  $out=shell_exec($cmd);
  echo('<br />shell_exec()<br />$out='.print_r($out,1));
?>
```

Output

```
HOME=/tmp; /usr/bin/libreoffice3.5 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_16_64.docx
exec()
$out=Array ( )
$ret=134
shell_exec()
$out=
```

Comment: Specify the full path to `/path/to/libreoffice3.5`. It may not be in the `$PATH` PHP is using.

Comment: I'm just checking, you are not in safe mode are you?

Comment: @Michael.  Thanks, but no difference.

Comment: @JRSofty.  Don't think so.  It is my own physical server, and I did not intentionally set it up with safe mode.

Comment: use the output parameter of the exec command to see if you get any error messages might be useful.

Comment: @Toby.  Tried to but nothing.  Maybe I am doing incorrectly.  Please see my edited original post which shows the output.  Thanks

Comment: Messing around some more, and get a return value of 134 for the exec() version only.  Is this a clue?

Comment: Well, I feel stupid.  Instead of HOME=/tmp, should have been HOME=/tmp/ayb

Answer (score 0):

Does Apache have the correct user permissions? If you're logged into SSH as root, then you'll have full access to commands; so you might need to upgrade Apache's permissions to certain directories.

You might also find it worthwhile to try out [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

It might also be a directory issue, as Michael pointed out. Point to the full directory path rather than a relative one.

Comment: When I enter into the command shell, I am logged in as root.  Note that I changed the permissions of tmp/ayb to 777 in an attempt to alleviate this.  Is there other types of "permissions" that I am missing?  Also, I already had tried shell_exec(), but no difference.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, just to rule something out, I tried the following PHP and it worked: exec('cp /tmp/ayb/document_16_64.docx /tmp/ayb/document_16_64_2.docx');